# After running flutter clean the project throwing gradle error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

After doing a flutter clean the following error is being shown when I try to run the project.

/../software/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/message_codecs.dart:580:29: Error: Expected ')' before this.
if (errorCode is String &flut& (errorMessage == null || errorMessage is String) && !buffer.hasRemaining)
^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'Development/software/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 991
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDevDebug'.

> Process 'command '
> Development/software/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit
> value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDevDebug failed with exit code 1

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you run `flutter doctor --verbose` and add the result to your question

Comment: • No issues found!

Answer (score 0):

Have you `Flutter pub get` after use `Flutter clean`

Comment: Yes it doesnt work. The error still stays